# Can't port Linux TCP socket program in C to Windows

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to import C programs, which demonstrate TCP socket programming in the Linux environment, into Windows. In the following two programs, the commented out `include` statements work in Linux and the `include`s below them are the Windows equivalent that I put. However, when I'm running these two programs, the server and the client produce the following errors respectively.

- **Error from simple_server**

> Socket received successfully...Failed to listen...

- **Error from simple_client**

> Read Error

All the equivalent Windows includes were taken from a long Stackoverflow searching session itself..:D. However, I'm stuck here not understanding why my server is not running. Any helpful advice and suggestions are highly appreciated.

#### My code

---

**simple_server.c**

```js
// #include <arpa/inet.h>
// #include <sys/socket.h>
// #include <netinet/in.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// #include <unistd.h>
#include <io.h>

// Windows equivalent to sleep() in unistd.h
#include <windows.h>
#define sleep(n) Sleep(n*1000)
#define usleep(n) Sleep(n/1000)

#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main (void){
  int listenfd, connfd = 0;

  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

  char send_buff[1024];
  int numrv;

  listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  printf("Socket received successfully...");

  memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
  memset(send_buff, '0', sizeof(send_buff));

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(50001);

  bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

  if(listen(listenfd,10) == -1){
      printf("Failed to listen..");
      return -1;
  }

  while(1){
connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);

strcpy(send_buff, "Message from the server");
write(connfd, send_buff, strlen(send_buff));

close(connfd);
sleep(1);
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

**simple_client.c**

```js
#include <sys/types.h>

// #include <arpa/inet.h>
// #include <sys/socket.h>
// #include <netinet/in.h>
// #include <netdb.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// #include <unistd.h>
#include <io.h>

#include <errno.h>

int main(void){
    int sockfd, n =0;
    char receive_buffer[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    memset(receive_buffer, '0', sizeof(receive_buffer));
    if((sockfd == socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
        printf("Error: couldn't receive socket.");
        return -1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    if(connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){

    }

    while ((n = read(sockfd, receive_buffer, sizeof(receive_buffer)-1)) > 0){
      receive_buffer[n] = 0;
      if(fputs(receive_buffer,stdout) == EOF){
          printf("\nError: fputs error");
      }
      printf("\n");
    }

    if(n<0){
        printf("\n Read Error");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want initialize the structure with `\0`, not with `0`. But since you explicitly set all relevant struct members, this should not be an issue. You probably have to set the socket option `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Comment: When you get an error it is of no use to anybody merely to print a piece of text of your own devising. Print the error, and post it here.

Comment: AFAIK, you must also intialize WinSock2 with `WSAStartup()` before you can use the functions in the library. I would propose to read the IMHO good [documentation (Getting Started with Winsock)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/getting-started-with-winsock) from Microsoft. There are also examples.